# How to solve $(y-\lambda)y''=1+(y')^2$? Is it the right catenary equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, optimization, mathematical-physics

Why is $(y-\lambda)y''=1+(y')^2 \tag{1}$ different from usual catenery equation?

How to solve $(y-\lambda)y''=1+(y')^2$?

I obtained (1) by
Let $\Gamma$ be a $C^2$ variation with fixed end points parametrized by $s$, i.e.
$\Gamma : \prod_{i=1}^n [-\epsilon_i, +\epsilon_i] \to C^{2}([a \ \ b], p, q) $
is a $C^2$ map such that for each $s\in\prod_{i=1}^n[-\epsilon_i, +\epsilon_i] $

\begin{align*}\Gamma_s \in C^{2}([a \ \ b], p, q)= \textit{the space of twice continuously differentiable paths from } p\ \text{to}\ q \\ =\{y\  \vert \ y:  [a \ \ b]\to \mathbb{R} \textit{ is a smoothdif curve such that  }  y(a)=p, \ y(b)=q\}\end{align*}

Then $\Gamma$ can be thought also as $\Gamma :\prod_{i=1}^n [-\epsilon_i, +\epsilon_i] \times [a \ \ b]\to \mathbb{R}$.

Length functional is given as
$g:C^{2}([a \ \ b], p, q)\to \mathbb{R}$
$g(y)=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2} dt$

Energy functional is given as
$f:C^{2}([a \ \ b], p, q)\to \mathbb{R}$
$f(y)=\int_a^b\Gamma\sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2} dt$

Given a $C^2$ variation $\Gamma : \prod_{i=1}^n [-\epsilon_i, +\epsilon_i] \to C^{2}([a \ \ b], p, q)$,

define
$G: \prod_{i=1}^n[-\epsilon_i, +\epsilon_i] \to \mathbb{R}$ as $
    G(s)=g(\Gamma_s)$

define $F: \prod_{i=1}^n[-\epsilon_i, +\epsilon_i] \to\mathbb{R}$ as 
$F(s)=f(\Gamma_s)$

For a fixed length $c\geq \sqrt{(b-a)^2 + (q-p)^2}$, if the restricted function $F \vert_{G^{-1}\{c\}}$ attains minimum at $s_*$ and if $\vec{\nabla}G\neq0$ there, by Lagrange multiplier theorem, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\vec{\nabla} F = \lambda \vec{\nabla} G \\ \text{i.e., } \frac{\partial}{\partial s_i}
 f(\Gamma_s)= \lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial s_i} g (\Gamma_s)$

$\frac {\partial} {\partial s_i} f(\Gamma_s)= \int_a^b\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial s}(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\Gamma(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{-1}{\  2}} \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial s \partial t} dt$

$\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial s_i}
 g(\Gamma_s)= \lambda \int_a^b(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial s \partial t}dt$

\begin{align*} \frac{\partial}{\partial s_i} f(\Gamma_s)-\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial s_i}
 g(\Gamma_s) &=\int_a^b\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial s_i}(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}+(\Gamma-\lambda)(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{-1}{\  2}} \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial s_i \partial t} dt 
 \\ &=\int_a^b \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial s_i}[(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{-1}{\  2}}-\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial t^2}(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{-3}{\  2}}(\Gamma - \lambda) ] dt 
 \\ &= \int_a^b \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial s_i}(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)^{\frac{-3}{\  2}}
 [(1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)-\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial t^2}(\Gamma - \lambda) ] dt=0 \end{align*}
for any  variation if and only if $\begin{align*} (1+(\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial t})^2)-\frac{\partial^2 \Gamma}{\partial t^2}(\Gamma - \lambda) =0 \end{align*}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redistribute the factors to
$$
\frac{y'y''}{1+y'^2}=\frac{y'}{y−λ}\implies 1+y'^2=C(y−λ)^2
$$
If you have an identity $1+A^2=B^2$ you can parametrize it as $A=\sinh(u)$, $B=\cosh(u)$. Thus set 
$$
y'=\sinh(u),\\\sqrt{C}(y−λ)=\cosh(u)
\\~\\
\implies \sqrt{C}y'=\sinh(u)u'\implies \sqrt{C}\sinh(u)=\sinh(u)u'\implies u'=\sqrt{C}$$
or
$$
y(x)=λ+\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}\cosh(\sqrt{C}x+D).
$$

Comment: I don't follow your $u$-substitution. Would help with more steps

Comment: If you have an identity $1+A^2=B^2$ you can parametrize it as $A=\sinh(u)$, $B=\cosh(u)$. The harder implicit assumption is that $u$ is a differentiable function in $x$, one would have to employ the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Now I do, but I still think your explanation is hard to follow. It's better to set $\sqrt{C}(y-\lambda) = \cosh (u)$ first, then derive the equation the regular way (through differentiation)

Comment: I thought the $\implies$ in your second line came from the first equation, instead of from differentiating the substitution $\sqrt{C}(y-\lambda) = \cosh(u)$ (what you intended). Maybe you should make it more clear

Comment: I inserted that extra step.

Comment: +1 really nice @LutzL